# Limit underline to the text

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, spacing, text-decorations

I'd like to have the underline for the text only and at the same keep the image part of the link:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<title>Test</title>

<style type="text/css">
a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
img {border:none; vertical-align:bottom; padding-left:15px}
</style>

<a href="#">Subscribe to feed<img src="http://www.google.com/phone/static/images/feed-icon.gif" alt=""></a>
```

The code result isn't the same in all major browsers.

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Just [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/g7dDf/) in Chrome and IE8.  Screw the others!

Comment: I've just tested YOUR code in IE6 and IE7 image is not underlined. So what is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q7CJB/)**

```
<style type="text/css">
    a, a:hover span { text-decoration:none; }
    a span { text-decoration: underline; }
    a img {
        border: none;
        vertical-align: bottom;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }
</style>

<a href="#">
    <span>Subscribe to feed</span>
    <img src="http://www.google.com/phone/static/images/feed-icon.gif" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: @Rain Lover: If you need IE6-specific solutions, please specify that in your question. You referenced "all major browsers", which many people will say does NOT include IE6.

Comment: "many people will say does NOT include IE6." You're right, but the bitter fact is many people still use it and that's why I test my codes in all browsers as well as IE6.

Answer (score 0):

```
a img {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: This was my original idea, and it only seemed to work because of a missing `;` in one of the OP's CSS declarations.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I wonder if you could provide the embed code that works for you.

Comment: I've just tested YOUR code in IE6 and IE7 image is not underlined. So what is the issue?

Comment: Would you please try it in Firefox, too? In Firefox it shows an extra continuous underline toward the image.

Comment: It is Firefox bug. Just wrap your image like another anchor: `<a href="#">My link!</a> <a href="#"><img ...></a>` or wrap your link as a span with underline: `<a href="#"><span class='underlined'>My link!</span><img ...></a>`